# WCF FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, wcf, filenotfoundexception

I am running WCF inside a Windows service. The service starts and runs fine, and I can access the service and call the WCF methods from the same machine, (using LocalHost as wcf server name),  but after a recent change, when I try to call one of the WCF methods from another workstation I am getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException and WCF Service crashes.  Before that it was working fine.

The error in the Application log on wcf server is as shown below: There is no indication as to what file it is unable to load.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-29T18:33:27.000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3292</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>LASAPPTEST.rose.portland.local</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Application: CoP.Enterprise.ServiceHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:   
System.IO.FileNotFoundException Stack: at CoP.LAS.LASServiceHostProcessManager.StartProcess() at  
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,  
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run  
(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at   
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,   
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()  
</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

ideas? is there any way to debug this and figure out where to go next? What file is it trying to load?

With hint from @seymour, FOUND THE ANSWER: Use the Wcf Trace Log capability 
(add following to web.config/app.config )

```
<system.diagnostics>
      <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="traceListener" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "C:\LASServices\LAS\Logs\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
      </sources>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

and use Wcf Trace Log Viewer (SvcTraceViewer.exe), to read the details for the FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Oh, the ever useful FNF exception, that doesn't tell you what goddamned file wasn't found.  Well, I'd suspect two things--either it's trying to load an assembly, or a file, which isn't there or is locked or is not the one being searched for.  So, are you trying to load a file in  StartProcess?  If so, stop doing it if it isn't there.  If not, bust out the fusion logger and see if you're having assembly load issues.

Comment: Any errors or other related information in the WCF trace log.  In the past, we have noticed service start-up error info in the trace file.

Comment: "but after a recent change" what did you change?

Comment: Found it, thanks to @Seymour reminding me to use Wcf Trace Log and Wcf Trave Log Viewer (SvcTraceViewer.exe).  In there, it tells you what file it can't load... In this case it was a third party dll that the service did not have a reference to, but which it needed because it was loading it dynamically using Assembly.Load and CreateInstance... I just had to copy that dll to the service folder.

Comment: Added the answer to help others searching for assistance. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we have found to help determine the root cause of WCF service host start-up issues, such as a `FileNotFoundException`, is to enable WCF Tracing. Oftentimes, the WCF Trace log will reveal issues that were previously “hidden”.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx